# Converting Veins Coordinates to GPS

Tags: openstreetmap, omnet++, veins

I am using realistic street networks imported from [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org) for simulations with Veins, for example the [Luxembourg scenario](https://github.com/lcodeca/LuSTScenario) from Lara Codeca. Now, to prepare a visualisation (using Google Earth), I want to export the vehicle positions in the simulation from SUMO or OmNET coordinates to GPS coordinates.

As material I have the OSM file used for generating the scenario, including the GPS positions of all nodes there. I was hoping to find a simple mapping from the simulation coordinates to GPS coordinates, for example, by knowing the GPS coordinates of the corners of the bounding box and the simulation playground.

Is there a simple way to make this conversion, and how can I find the actual corners that were used by the OSM conversion when generating the playground?

Comment: If you used netconvert to create a .net.xml from the .osm file, the network will have stored details on the projection used. You can quickly check by running the SUMO simulation in GUI mode: if projection information is available, you should see your mouse pointer's position as both x/y and lon/lat in the bottom right corner of the window.

Comment: @ChristophSommer I only see another set of x/y around 3e5/5.5e6, the .net.xml file contains the following line:     <location netOffset="-285448.66,-5492398.13" convBoundary="0.00,0.00,13613.76,11455.04" origBoundary="6.030969,49.549099,6.216758,49.652578" projParameter="+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"/>
This should get me started, I will check the SUMO docs. Is there some way to read the projection information from SUMO using traci?

Comment: You might have built your SUMO binary without PROJ or GDAL support. SUMO will then not be able to invert the projection for you. I just tried running the Veins example scenario: at least for this scenario, `traci->getLonLat(mobility->getCurrentPosition())` returns sensible coordinates like [11.0313, 49.5739](https://www.google.com/maps/place/49.5739,11.0312)

Comment: @mwil.me can you please explain how you did the visualization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion works as follows:

### 1. Accessing the Location Information from OmNET

```cpp
// Adapt your path to the mobility module here  
Veins::TraCIMobility* mobility =
  check_and_cast<Veins::TraCIMobility*>(
    getParentModule()->getSubmodule("veinsmobility"));

Veins::TraCICommandInterface* traci = mobility->getCommandInterface();

Coord currPos = mobility->getCurrentPosition();
std::pair<double, double> currLonLat = traci->getLonLat(currPos);
```

`getLonLat()` returned absolute 2D coordinates for me, so there is a conversion step required.

### 2. Finding the Transformation

The .net.xml file from SUMO contains the required transformation. The `<location>` tag contains the attributes `netOffset` and `projParameters` that are needed.

For the Luxembourg scenario, these are

```
netOffset="-285448.66,-5492398.13"
projParameter="+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
```

### 3. Inversing the Transformation

The library [PROJ.4](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4) can be used to do the inversion. A Python interface is also available ([pyproj](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyproj)).

```py
import pyproj

projection = pyproj.Proj(
  "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")

# x, y obtained from OmNET
lon, lat = projection(x, y, inverse=True)
```

In case only the relative location information is available, the x, y values must be adjusted first by adding the netOffset values to them.

### Edit

Only the first step is necessary when you build SUMO `--with-proj-gdal` support, the result of `getLonLat()` will be in the desired format immediately.

Comment: I was able to create a SUMO network from an OSM map and was able to run the Veins simulation on OMNet++ but the simulation playground does not display the polygon shapes. Seeing that you have worked on this, can you please let me know if you have faced similar issues?