# I'm trying to implement GPS data into the waveshortmessage, but i'm having problems implementing omnet2traci function

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm using `omnet5`, `veins 4.4`, and `sumo 0.25`. I've looked at [Converting Veins Coordinates to GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123909/converting-veins-coordinates-to-gps/35151712) which didn't help much since i have the updated version.

This one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650825/connection-to-traci-server-lost-check-your-servers-log-error-message-88-soc seems like it might work with a little error checking, but I'm not sure what the user did to make it work.

I've seen that you can use omnet2traci to convert the regular coordinates to the sumo ones, but I'm having trouble implementing it properly. When I tried calling it in message with:

```
class  Veins::TraCIConnection::omnet2traci;
```

then using:

```
Veins::TraCICoord gpspos = omnet2traci(senderPos);
```

but I'm getting undeclared identifier error. I tried changing to `.cc` and `.h code` to compensate for it by creating a small copy of the `omnet2traci coding from TraCIConnection`. After all that it gives me errors:

```
omnetpp-5.0/include/omnetpp/cdynamicexpression.h:50:9: error: expected identifier
        ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV, MOD, POW, NEG,
        ^
.\veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConstants.h:707:13: note: expanded from macro 'ADD'
#define ADD 0x80
            ^

omnetpp-5.0/include/omnetpp/coutvector.h:66:27: error: expected identifier
    enum Type { TYPE_INT, TYPE_DOUBLE, TYPE_ENUM };
                          ^
.\veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConstants.h:304:21: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_DOUBLE'
#define TYPE_DOUBLE 0x0B
                    ^
```

At this point it seems like it working around the problem and hoping it works instead of actually solving the problem. Full code below, added in parts are starred. *note I had to snip the end parts of the .cc code because it went over the text limit, but nothing was changed.

**Waveshortmessage.msg**

```
 //Waveshortmessage.msg
    cplusplus {{
  **#include <stdint.h>
    #include "veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIBuffer.h"
    #include "veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h"
    #include "veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.h"
    #include "veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConstants.h"
    #include "veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICoord.h"**
    #include "veins/base/utils/Coord.h"

    }}


    class noncobject Coord;
   **class noncobject Veins::TraCICoord;
    class  Veins::TraCIConnection::omnet2traci;**




    packet WaveShortMessage {
        //Version of the Wave Short Message
        int wsmVersion = 0;
        //Determine which security mechanism was used
        int securityType = 0;
        //Channel Number on which this packet was sent
        int channelNumber;
        //Data rate with which this packet was sent
        int dataRate = 1;
        //Power Level with which this packet was sent
        int priority = 3;
        //Unique number to identify the service
        int psid = 0;
        //Provider Service Context
        string psc = "Service with some Data";
        //Length of Wave Short Message
        int wsmLength;
        //Data of Wave Short Message
        string wsmData = "Some Data";

        int senderAddress = 0;
        int recipientAddress = -1;
        int serial = 0;
        Coord senderPos;

        **Veins::TraCICoord gpspos = omnet2traci(senderPos);**

        simtime_t timestamp = 0;

    }
```

**Waveshortmessage.cc**

```
//waveshortmessage.cc
// Generated file, do not edit! Created by nedtool 5.0 from veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage.msg.
//
**#define WANT_WINSOCK2
#include <platdep/sockets.h>
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__) || defined(_WIN64)
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#else
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif

#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

//#include "veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.h"
#include "veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConstants.h"

#define MYDEBUG EV**

// Disable warnings about unused variables, empty switch stmts, etc:
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#  pragma warning(disable:4101)
#  pragma warning(disable:4065)
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "WaveShortMessage_m.h"

namespace omnetpp {

// Template pack/unpack rules. They are declared *after* a1l type-specific pack functions for multiple reasons.
// They are in the omnetpp namespace, to allow them to be found by argument-dependent lookup via the cCommBuffer argument

// Packing/unpacking an std::vector
template<typename T, typename A>
void doParsimPacking(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *buffer, const std::vector<T,A>& v)
{
    int n = v.size();
    doParsimPacking(buffer, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        doParsimPacking(buffer, v[i]);
}

template<typename T, typename A>
void doParsimUnpacking(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *buffer, std::vector<T,A>& v)
{
    int n;
    doParsimUnpacking(buffer, n);
    v.resize(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        doParsimUnpacking(buffer, v[i]);
}

// Packing/unpacking an std::list
template<typename T, typename A>
void doParsimPacking(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *buffer, const std::list<T,A>& l)
{
    doParsimPacking(buffer, (int)l.size());
    for (typename std::list<T,A>::const_iterator it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it)
        doParsimPacking(buffer, (T&)*it);
}

template<typename T, typename A>
void doParsimUnpacking(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *buffer, std::list<T,A>& l)
{
    int n;
    doParsimUnpacking(buffer, n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        l.push_back(T());
        doParsimUnpacking(buffer, l.back());
    }
}

// Packing/unpacking an std::set
template<typename T, typename Tr, typename A>
void doParsimPacking(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *buffer, const std::set<T,Tr,A>& s)
{
    doParsimPacking(buffer, (int)s.size());
    for (typename std::set<T,Tr,A>::const_iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
        doParsimPacking(buffer, *it);
}

template<typename T, typename Tr, typename A>
void doParsimUnpacking(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *buffer, std::set<T,Tr,A>& s)
{
    int n;
    doParsimUnpacking(buffer, n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        T x;
        doParsimUnpacking(buffer, x);
        s.insert(x);
    }
}

// Packing/unpacking an std::map
template<typename K, typename V, typename Tr, typename A>
void doParsimPacking(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *buffer, const std::map<K,V,Tr,A>& m)
{
    doParsimPacking(buffer, (int)m.size());
    for (typename std::map<K,V,Tr,A>::const_iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
        doParsimPacking(buffer, it->first);
        doParsimPacking(buffer, it->second);
    }
}

template<typename K, typename V, typename Tr, typename A>
void doParsimUnpacking(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *buffer, std::map<K,V,Tr,A>& m)
{
    int n;
    doParsimUnpacking(buffer, n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        K k; V v;
        doParsimUnpacking(buffer, k);
        doParsimUnpacking(buffer, v);
        m[k] = v;
    }
}

// Default pack/unpack function for arrays
template<typename T>
void doParsimArrayPacking(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *b, const T *t, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        doParsimPacking(b, t[i]);
}

template<typename T>
void doParsimArrayUnpacking(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *b, T *t, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        doParsimUnpacking(b, t[i]);
}

// Default rule to prevent compiler from choosing base class' doParsimPacking() function
template<typename T>
void doParsimPacking(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *, const T& t)
{
    throw omnetpp::cRuntimeError("Parsim error: no doParsimPacking() function for type %s", omnetpp::opp_typename(typeid(t)));
}

template<typename T>
void doParsimUnpacking(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *, T& t)
{
    throw omnetpp::cRuntimeError("Parsim error: no doParsimUnpacking() function for type %s", omnetpp::opp_typename(typeid(t)));
}

}  // namespace omnetpp


// forward
template<typename T, typename A>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<T,A>& vec);

// Template rule which fires if a struct or class doesn't have operator<<
template<typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const T&) {return out;}

// operator<< for std::vector<T>
template<typename T, typename A>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<T,A>& vec)
{
    out.put('{');
    for(typename std::vector<T,A>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it != vec.begin()) {
            out.put(','); out.put(' ');
        }
        out << *it;
    }
    out.put('}');

    char buf[32];
    sprintf(buf, " (size=%u)", (unsigned int)vec.size());
    out.write(buf, strlen(buf));
    return out;
}
**Veins::TraCICoord Veins::TraCIConnection::omnet2traci(Coord coord) const {
    return TraCICoord(coord.x + netbounds1.x - margin, (netbounds2.y - netbounds1.y) - (coord.y - netbounds1.y) + margin);
}

std::list<Veins::TraCICoord> Veins::TraCIConnection::omnet2traci(const std::list<Coord>& list) const {
    std::list<TraCICoord> result;
    std::transform(list.begin(), list.end(), std::back_inserter(result), std::bind1st(std::mem_fun<TraCICoord, TraCIConnection, Coord>(&TraCIConnection::omnet2traci), this));
    return result;
}**
Register_Class(WaveShortMessage);

WaveShortMessage::WaveShortMessage(const char *name, int kind) : ::omnetpp::cPacket(name,kind)
{
    this->wsmVersion = 0;
    this->securityType = 0;
    this->channelNumber = 0;
    this->dataRate = 1;
    this->priority = 3;
    this->psid = 0;
    this->psc = "Service with some Data";
    this->wsmLength = 0;
    this->wsmData = "Some Data";
    this->senderAddress = 0;
    this->recipientAddress = -1;
    this->serial = 0;
    this->gpspos = omnet2traci(senderPos);
    this->timestamp = 0;
}

WaveShortMessage::WaveShortMessage(const WaveShortMessage& other) : ::omnetpp::cPacket(other)
{
    copy(other);
}

WaveShortMessage::~WaveShortMessage()
{
}

WaveShortMessage& WaveShortMessage::operator=(const WaveShortMessage& other)
{
    if (this==&other) return *this;
    ::omnetpp::cPacket::operator=(other);
    copy(other);
    return *this;
}

void WaveShortMessage::copy(const WaveShortMessage& other)
{
    this->wsmVersion = other.wsmVersion;
    this->securityType = other.securityType;
    this->channelNumber = other.channelNumber;
    this->dataRate = other.dataRate;
    this->priority = other.priority;
    this->psid = other.psid;
    this->psc = other.psc;
    this->wsmLength = other.wsmLength;
    this->wsmData = other.wsmData;
    this->senderAddress = other.senderAddress;
    this->recipientAddress = other.recipientAddress;
    this->serial = other.serial;
    this->senderPos = other.senderPos;
    this->gpspos = other.gpspos;
    this->timestamp = other.timestamp;
}

void WaveShortMessage::parsimPack(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *b) const
{
    ::omnetpp::cPacket::parsimPack(b);
    doParsimPacking(b,this->wsmVersion);
    doParsimPacking(b,this->securityType);
    doParsimPacking(b,this->channelNumber);
    doParsimPacking(b,this->dataRate);
    doParsimPacking(b,this->priority);
    doParsimPacking(b,this->psid);
    doParsimPacking(b,this->psc);
    doParsimPacking(b,this->wsmLength);
    doParsimPacking(b,this->wsmData);
    doParsimPacking(b,this->senderAddress);
    doParsimPacking(b,this->recipientAddress);
    doParsimPacking(b,this->serial);
    doParsimPacking(b,this->senderPos);
    doParsimPacking(b,this->gpspos);
    doParsimPacking(b,this->timestamp);
}

void WaveShortMessage::parsimUnpack(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *b)
{
    ::omnetpp::cPacket::parsimUnpack(b);
    doParsimUnpacking(b,this->wsmVersion);
    doParsimUnpacking(b,this->securityType);
    doParsimUnpacking(b,this->channelNumber);
    doParsimUnpacking(b,this->dataRate);
    doParsimUnpacking(b,this->priority);
    doParsimUnpacking(b,this->psid);
    doParsimUnpacking(b,this->psc);
    doParsimUnpacking(b,this->wsmLength);
    doParsimUnpacking(b,this->wsmData);
    doParsimUnpacking(b,this->senderAddress);
    doParsimUnpacking(b,this->recipientAddress);
    doParsimUnpacking(b,this->serial);
    doParsimUnpacking(b,this->senderPos);
    doParsimUnpacking(b,this->gpspos);
    doParsimUnpacking(b,this->timestamp);
}

int WaveShortMessage::getWsmVersion() const
{
    return this->wsmVersion;
}

void WaveShortMessage::setWsmVersion(int wsmVersion)
{
    this->wsmVersion = wsmVersion;
}

int WaveShortMessage::getSecurityType() const
{
    return this->securityType;
}

void WaveShortMessage::setSecurityType(int securityType)
{
    this->securityType = securityType;
}

int WaveShortMessage::getChannelNumber() const
{
    return this->channelNumber;
}

void WaveShortMessage::setChannelNumber(int channelNumber)
{
    this->channelNumber = channelNumber;
}

int WaveShortMessage::getDataRate() const
{
    return this->dataRate;
}

void WaveShortMessage::setDataRate(int dataRate)
{
    this->dataRate = dataRate;
}

int WaveShortMessage::getPriority() const
{
    return this->priority;
}

void WaveShortMessage::setPriority(int priority)
{
    this->priority = priority;
}

int WaveShortMessage::getPsid() const
{
    return this->psid;
}

void WaveShortMessage::setPsid(int psid)
{
    this->psid = psid;
}

const char * WaveShortMessage::getPsc() const
{
    return this->psc.c_str();
}

void WaveShortMessage::setPsc(const char * psc)
{
    this->psc = psc;
}

int WaveShortMessage::getWsmLength() const
{
    return this->wsmLength;
}

void WaveShortMessage::setWsmLength(int wsmLength)
{
    this->wsmLength = wsmLength;
}

const char * WaveShortMessage::getWsmData() const
{
    return this->wsmData.c_str();
}

void WaveShortMessage::setWsmData(const char * wsmData)
{
    this->wsmData = wsmData;
}

int WaveShortMessage::getSenderAddress() const
{
    return this->senderAddress;
}

void WaveShortMessage::setSenderAddress(int senderAddress)
{
    this->senderAddress = senderAddress;
}

int WaveShortMessage::getRecipientAddress() const
{
    return this->recipientAddress;
}

void WaveShortMessage::setRecipientAddress(int recipientAddress)
{
    this->recipientAddress = recipientAddress;
}

int WaveShortMessage::getSerial() const
{
    return this->serial;
}

void WaveShortMessage::setSerial(int serial)
{
    this->serial = serial;
}

Coord& WaveShortMessage::getSenderPos()
{
    return this->senderPos;
}

void WaveShortMessage::setSenderPos(const Coord& senderPos)
{
    this->senderPos = senderPos;
}

Veins::TraCICoord& WaveShortMessage::getGpspos()
{
    return this->gpspos;
}

void WaveShortMessage::setGpspos(const Veins::TraCICoord& gpspos)
{
    this->gpspos = gpspos;
}

::omnetpp::simtime_t WaveShortMessage::getTimestamp() const
{
    return this->timestamp;
}

void WaveShortMessage::setTimestamp(::omnetpp::simtime_t timestamp)
{
    this->timestamp = timestamp;
}

class WaveShortMessageDescriptor : public omnetpp::cClassDescriptor
{
  private:
    mutable const char **propertynames;
  public:
    WaveShortMessageDescriptor();
    virtual ~WaveShortMessageDescriptor();

    virtual bool doesSupport(omnetpp::cObject *obj) const override;
    virtual const char **getPropertyNames() const override;
    virtual const char *getProperty(const char *propertyname) const override;
    virtual int getFieldCount() const override;
    virtual const char *getFieldName(int field) const override;
    virtual int findField(const char *fieldName) const override;
    virtual unsigned int getFieldTypeFlags(int field) const override;
    virtual const char *getFieldTypeString(int field) const override;
    virtual const char **getFieldPropertyNames(int field) const override;
    virtual const char *getFieldProperty(int field, const char *propertyname) const override;
    virtual int getFieldArraySize(void *object, int field) const override;

    virtual std::string getFieldValueAsString(void *object, int field, int i) const override;
    virtual bool setFieldValueAsString(void *object, int field, int i, const char *value) const override;

    virtual const char *getFieldStructName(int field) const override;
    virtual void *getFieldStructValuePointer(void *object, int field, int i) const override;
};

Register_ClassDescriptor(WaveShortMessageDescriptor);

WaveShortMessageDescriptor::WaveShortMessageDescriptor() : omnetpp::cClassDescriptor("WaveShortMessage", "omnetpp::cPacket")
{
    propertynames = nullptr;
}

WaveShortMessageDescriptor::~WaveShortMessageDescriptor()
{
    delete[] propertynames;
}

bool WaveShortMessageDescriptor::doesSupport(omnetpp::cObject *obj) const
{
    return dynamic_cast<WaveShortMessage *>(obj)!=nullptr;
}

const char **WaveShortMessageDescriptor::getPropertyNames() const
{
    if (!propertynames) {
        static const char *names[] = {  nullptr };
        omnetpp::cClassDescriptor *basedesc = getBaseClassDescriptor();
        const char **basenames = basedesc ? basedesc->getPropertyNames() : nullptr;
        propertynames = mergeLists(basenames, names);
    }
    return propertynames;
}

const char *WaveShortMessageDescriptor::getProperty(const char *propertyname) const
{
    omnetpp::cClassDescriptor *basedesc = getBaseClassDescriptor();
    return basedesc ? basedesc->getProperty(propertyname) : nullptr;
}

int WaveShortMessageDescriptor::getFieldCount() const
{
    omnetpp::cClassDescriptor *basedesc = getBaseClassDescriptor();
    return basedesc ? 15+basedesc->getFieldCount() : 15;
}

unsigned int WaveShortMessageDescriptor::getFieldTypeFlags(int field) const
{
    omnetpp::cClassDescriptor *basedesc = getBaseClassDescriptor();
    if (basedesc) {
        if (field < basedesc->getFieldCount())
            return basedesc->getFieldTypeFlags(field);
        field -= basedesc->getFieldCount();
    }
    static unsigned int fieldTypeFlags[] = {
        FD_ISEDITABLE,
        FD_ISEDITABLE,
        FD_ISEDITABLE,
        FD_ISEDITABLE,
        FD_ISEDITABLE,
        FD_ISEDITABLE,
        FD_ISEDITABLE,
        FD_ISEDITABLE,
        FD_ISEDITABLE,
        FD_ISEDITABLE,
        FD_ISEDITABLE,
        FD_ISEDITABLE,
        FD_ISCOMPOUND,
        FD_ISCOMPOUND,
        FD_ISEDITABLE,
    };
    return (field>=0 && field<15) ? fieldTypeFlags[field] : 0;
}

const char *WaveShortMessageDescriptor::getFieldName(int field) const
{
    omnetpp::cClassDescriptor *basedesc = getBaseClassDescriptor();
    if (basedesc) {
        if (field < basedesc->getFieldCount())
            return basedesc->getFieldName(field);
        field -= basedesc->getFieldCount();
    }
    static const char *fieldNames[] = {
        "wsmVersion",
        "securityType",
        "channelNumber",
        "dataRate",
        "priority",
        "psid",
        "psc",
        "wsmLength",
        "wsmData",
        "senderAddress",
        "recipientAddress",
        "serial",
        "senderPos",
        "gpspos",
        "timestamp",
    };
    return (field>=0 && field<15) ? fieldNames[field] : nullptr;
}
```

**Waveshortmessage.h**

```
//Waveshortmessage.h
// Generated file, do not edit! Created by nedtool 5.0 from veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage.msg.
//

#ifndef __WAVESHORTMESSAGE_M_H
#define __WAVESHORTMESSAGE_M_H

#include <omnetpp.h>

// nedtool version check
#define MSGC_VERSION 0x0500
#if (MSGC_VERSION!=OMNETPP_VERSION)
#    error Version mismatch! Probably this file was generated by an earlier version of nedtool: 'make clean' should help.
#endif



// cplusplus {{
** #include <stdint.h>
#include "veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIBuffer.h"
#include "veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h"
#include "veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.h"
#include "veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConstants.h"
#include "veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICoord.h" **
#include "veins/base/utils/Coord.h"
// }}

/**
 * Class generated from <tt>veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage.msg:40</tt> by nedtool.
 * <pre>
 * packet WaveShortMessage
 * {
 *     //Version of the Wave Short Message
 *     int wsmVersion = 0;
 *     //Determine which security mechanism was used
 *     int securityType = 0;
 *     //Channel Number on which this packet was sent
 *     int channelNumber;
 *     //Data rate with which this packet was sent
 *     int dataRate = 1;
 *     //Power Level with which this packet was sent
 *     int priority = 3;
 *     //Unique number to identify the service
 *     int psid = 0;
 *     //Provider Service Context
 *     string psc = "Service with some Data";
 *     //Length of Wave Short Message
 *     int wsmLength;
 *     //Data of Wave Short Message
 *     string wsmData = "Some Data";
 * 
 *     int senderAddress = 0;
 *     int recipientAddress = -1;
 *     int serial = 0;
 *     Coord senderPos;
 * 
 *     Veins::TraCICoord gpspos = omnet2traci(senderPos);
 * 
 *     simtime_t timestamp = 0;
 * 
 * }
 * </pre>
 */
class WaveShortMessage : public ::omnetpp::cPacket
{
  protected:
    int wsmVersion;
    int securityType;
    int channelNumber;
    int dataRate;
    int priority;
    int psid;
    ::omnetpp::opp_string psc;
    int wsmLength;
    ::omnetpp::opp_string wsmData;
    int senderAddress;
    int recipientAddress;
    int serial;
    Coord senderPos;
    Veins::TraCICoord gpspos;
    ::omnetpp::simtime_t timestamp;

  private:
    void copy(const WaveShortMessage& other);

  protected:
    // protected and unimplemented operator==(), to prevent accidental usage
    bool operator==(const WaveShortMessage&);

  public:
    WaveShortMessage(const char *name=nullptr, int kind=0);
    WaveShortMessage(const WaveShortMessage& other);
    virtual ~WaveShortMessage();
    WaveShortMessage& operator=(const WaveShortMessage& other);
    virtual WaveShortMessage *dup() const {return new WaveShortMessage(*this);}
    virtual void parsimPack(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *b) const;
    virtual void parsimUnpack(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *b);

    // field getter/setter methods
    virtual int getWsmVersion() const;
    virtual void setWsmVersion(int wsmVersion);
    virtual int getSecurityType() const;
    virtual void setSecurityType(int securityType);
    virtual int getChannelNumber() const;
    virtual void setChannelNumber(int channelNumber);
    virtual int getDataRate() const;
    virtual void setDataRate(int dataRate);
    virtual int getPriority() const;
    virtual void setPriority(int priority);
    virtual int getPsid() const;
    virtual void setPsid(int psid);
    virtual const char * getPsc() const;
    virtual void setPsc(const char * psc);
    virtual int getWsmLength() const;
    virtual void setWsmLength(int wsmLength);
    virtual const char * getWsmData() const;
    virtual void setWsmData(const char * wsmData);
    virtual int getSenderAddress() const;
    virtual void setSenderAddress(int senderAddress);
    virtual int getRecipientAddress() const;
    virtual void setRecipientAddress(int recipientAddress);
    virtual int getSerial() const;
    virtual void setSerial(int serial);
    virtual Coord& getSenderPos();
    virtual const Coord& getSenderPos() const {return const_cast<WaveShortMessage*>(this)->getSenderPos();}
    virtual void setSenderPos(const Coord& senderPos);
    virtual Veins::TraCICoord& getGpspos();
    virtual const Veins::TraCICoord& getGpspos() const {return const_cast<WaveShortMessage*>(this)->getGpspos();}
    virtual void setGpspos(const Veins::TraCICoord& gpspos);
    virtual ::omnetpp::simtime_t getTimestamp() const;
    virtual void setTimestamp(::omnetpp::simtime_t timestamp);

  **Coord traci2omnet(Veins::TraCICoord coord) const;
                std::list<Coord> traci2omnet(const std::list<Veins::TraCICoord>&) const;


                Veins::TraCICoord omnet2traci(Coord coord) const;
                std::list<Veins::TraCICoord> omnet2traci(const std::list<Coord>&) const;**
};

inline void doParsimPacking(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *b, const WaveShortMessage& obj) {obj.parsimPack(b);}
inline void doParsimUnpacking(omnetpp::cCommBuffer *b, WaveShortMessage& obj) {obj.parsimUnpack(b);}


#endif // ifndef __WAVESHORTMESSAGE_M_H
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I am working with localization in VANETs and I was facing the same problem.

As you can see in veins FAQ SUMO and OMNeT++ use different coordinate systems, so when you call `mobility->getCurrentPosition()` you get omnet coordinates not sumo coordinates.

I make some tests with proj4 C library and the values not was matching...

As me, probably you looking for the real sumo coordinates and for this you need call `TraCIConnection::omnet2traci`. But the problem is that not exists in veins a direct interface to access the object `connection` via `TraCICommandInterface`.

To overcome this trick I implemented one public method directly in the class `TraCICommandInterface` the signature of the method is the same of `getLonLat` method the diference is that inside I return the sumo coordinates calling the method `omnet2traci'. Now I can get the real sumo coordinates and use this for work with my real GPS dataset and one deadreckoning technique that I've implemented.

Follows the code of the method:

```
std::pair<double, double> TraCICommandInterface::getTraCIXY(const Coord& coord){
    TraCICoord newCoord;
    newCoord = connection.omnet2traci(coord);
    return std::make_pair(newCoord.x, newCoord.y);
}
```

In your application class call this method using one TracICommandInterface object:

```
TraCIMobility* mobility;
TraCICommandInterface* traci;
```

Now in your `initialize` method instantiate this objects getting the active modules and *traci* interface:

```
 mobility = TraCIMobilityAccess().get(getParentModule());
 traci = mobility->getCommandInterface();
```

Now you will have this:

**These are omnet++ cordinates:**

```
Coord coordOmnet = mobility->getCurrentPosition();
```

**These are sumo coordinates calling our implement method:**

```
std::pair<double,double> coordTraCI = traci->getTraCIXY(mobility->getCurrentPosition());
```

Best Regards,

Pedro.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, this is exactly what I'm looking for, but I'm having a few problems with the implementation of your method. I've tried to use the `TraCICommandInterface` and `TraCIDemo11p` to set it up and WaveShortMessage to implement it similar to `Coord`. If you don't mind helping a little further, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hi @creepus I need more information in order to give you one feedback. Could you explain how you tried implement the method to obtain sumo coordinates? If possible paste some parts of your code.
Cheers,
Pedro.

Comment: in TraciCommandInterface.cc `std::pair<double, double> TraCICommandInterface::getLonLat(const Coord& coord) {
 TraCIBuffer request;
 ...
}

/*std::pair<double, double> TraCICommandInterface::getTraCIXY(const Coord& coord){
    TraCICoord newCoord;
    newCoord = connection.omnet2traci(coord);
    return std::make_pair(newCoord.x, newCoord.y);
} */
void TraCICommandInterface::GuiView::setScheme(std::string name) {
 ...}`

Comment: in TraCICommandInterface.h `std::pair<uint32_t, std::string> getVersion();
  std::pair<double, double> getLonLat(const Coord&);
  **//std::pair<double, double> getTraCIXY(const Coord&);**
  double getDistance(const Coord& position1, const Coord& position2, bool returnDrivingDistance);`

Comment: In TraCIDemo11p.cc `void TraCIDemo11p::handleParkingUpdate(cObject* obj) {
 isParking = mobility->getParkingState();
 if (sendWhileParking == false) {
  if (isParking == true) {
   (FindModule<BaseConnectionManager*>::findGlobalModule())->unregisterNic(this->getParentModule()->getSubmodule("nic"));
  }
  else {
   Coord pos = mobility->getCurrentPosition();
   **std::pair<double,double> coordTraCI = traci->getTraCIXY(mobility->getCurrentPosition());**
   ...
}`

Comment: in WaveShortMessage.msg `class noncobject Coord;

**//class noncobject CoordTraCI;**

packet WaveShortMessage {
 //Version of the Wave Short Message
 int wsmVersion = 0;
 //Determine which security mechanism was used
 int securityType = 0;
 //Channel Number on which this packet was sent
 int channelNumber;
 //Data rate with which this packet was sent
 int dataRate = 1;
 //Power Level with which this packet was sent
 int priority = 3;
 //Unique number to identify the service
...

 Coord senderPos;
 
 **//CoordTraCI gpspos;**

}`

Comment: I tried to include as many changes as possible with such a small character limit, I hope this helps. Thank you very much @Pedro

Comment: Hi @creepus, I noticed that you is using 'CoordTraCI' in _WaveShortMessage.msg_  but probably this class isn't visiblle here.
See in the begin of the file _WaveShortMessage.msg_ this part:
'cplusplus {{
#include "veins/base/utils/Coord.h"
}}'
You have two ways to make this works: 
You can use the type `Coord` instead of `CoordTraCI` because anyway your coordinates are x,y,z coordinates. So the class `Coord` also works.
The second choose is import the _.h_ file of `CoordTraCI.`

Comment: Another recommendation is not change the class TraCIDemo11p directly. Probably you will have one more clear project if you extends the Application layer class that you want to use. 

In my case I am extending the BaseWaveAppLayer class of veins.

In your case if you want use the features of `TraCIDemo11p` only extends it in a new one project and modify the methods that you want.

Hope that this works. If your problem with coordinates was solved, and if you dont mind, could you mark my first answer as correct? This will help another people. 

Best Regards.

Pedro.

Answer (score 0):

What is the main reason to convert the positions?

Why not use the [OMNet/Veins](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.cc#L198) - [SUMO/TraCi](http://www.sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Vehicle_Value_Retrieval#Command_0xa4:_Get_Vehicle_Variable) coordinate?

Comment: The simulation works fine with the regular coordinates and provide other parts of useful information. I'm trying to modify the simulation in order to get more realistic data that can be compared to real world situations. Strategic placement of the RSUs, controlled accident information, and directional messaging.