# How can one randomly place RSUs inside a Sumo simulation map during an OMNET++/Veins simulation?

Tags: omnet++, veins

First of all, this question or its variation is probably asked a large number of times. I apologise for the reiteration.

***Problem statement:*** I am trying to generate 'n' static RSU nodes with random initial positions. I am using `LinearMobility`and setting the speed etc. to 0 to achieve static-ness of RSUs. **N.B.** The vehicles are generated on fly from sumo through TraCI (this is working fine). ***The aim is to generate the RSUs such that, they are inside the area of the map, in the vicinity of where the vehicles are moving.***

But I am unable to do that. A lot of RSUs are generated, spread in the grey area (the playground) outside the map (which usually is at the bottom right corner), and I could not find a work around. (Being inexperienced with OMNET++) I strongly suspect this is wrong, because surely the road side units cannot be outside the map!

Is there a way such that the playground area can be aligned with the map area? If, yes then I think by knowing the 4 corner coordinates of the SUMO map, it should be possible to restrict the positions of the RSUs to the more or less within a rectangular Coordinate range. I would then use something like the following to generate RSUs: (#suppose the corners are [(1000,1000),(1500,1000),(1000, 1500),(1500,1500)])

```
network testNetwork extends Scenario
{   
    parameters:
        int numRSUs;
        @display("bgb=$playgroundSizeX,$playgroundSizeY");
    submodules:
        rsu[numRSUs]: RSU {
            mobilityType = "LinearMobility";
            mobility.x = uniform(1000, 1500);
            mobility.y = uniform(1000, 1500);
            mobility.z = 0;
            mobility.speed = 0;
            mobility.angle = 0;
            mobility.acceleration = 0;
            mobility.updateInterval =0;
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
}
```

Is this possible or even remotely a good idea? Can anybody please let me know if there is a way to solve this?

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't support using the `\`` for code blocks, only lines. Next time, please select your code and press the code format button.

Comment: Your problem is probably related to the fact that you're comparing SUMO and OMNeT++ Coordinates. The applications use different coordinate systems, unfortunately. Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123909/converting-veins-coordinates-to-gps) might help.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I knew that SUMO and OMNet++ use different coordinate system. Yet the link helped me. It gave me a good idea how to do the transformation and how to access those functions !!

Comment: @Anirban Das If your problem is solved, you might want to add an answer with the solution to your (own) question. This will help other users who face a similar problem in the future.

Comment: @AnirbanDas I have the same problem, could you please explain briefly how you solved it?